# Can I add checked bags after online check-in (American)

Tags: luggage, american-airlines

I have an international flight with American (booked through BA). Am I able to add additional checked bags after I have completed online check-in when at the airport, as I was unable to do so online while checking in?

Comment: Yes, but they may charge you more.

Comment: In normal circumstances they'd be within their rights to refuse to carry the extra bag, but at the moment I'm sure they'll have plenty luggage space. AA publishes baggage fees online but BA doesn't: https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/support/optional-service-fees.jsp

Comment: You can always add more bags online as soon as you are done packing and you realize there are gonna be more bags. At the airport they will accept the bags but may charge you more than what it costs online. https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/checked-baggage-allowances

Answer (score 2):

They will always gladly take your money (and your luggage).

Just make sure to be early enough at the airport; there are deadlines for the luggage dropoff, and they are earlier than the 'just-walk-to-the-gate' deadlines. Typically, they close hard an hour before the flight, but check yourself if you plan to cut it tight.